# Attachment if file present in mailables - Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.5

Up until recently I had this code to send email and attach file if it was defined in the model:

```
Mail::send('emails.new_'.$itemtype.'_response', ['lead' => $lead,'object' => $object, 'email' => $email_recipee, 'email_subject'=>$email_subject, 'email_assigner'=>$email_assigner], function ($m) use ( $email_recipee, $object, $lead, $email_assignee,$itemtype,$email_subject,$email_assigner) {
            $m->to($email_recipee, 'Mail sent by me!')->subject($email_subject);

    if($object->takealook_FILE !='' && filesize($object->takealook_FILE) < 2024128) {
                $m->attach($object->takealook_FILE);
            } 
    if($object->quotation_sheet !='' && filesize($object->quotation_sheet) < 2024128) {
          $m->attach($object->quotation_sheet);
            } 
});
```

### the problem

Now I use this code:

```
Mail::to($email_assigner)->cc($email_recipee)->queue(new TaskDeliverResults($object));
```

### to do

I am not familiar with the syntax well enough. How to merge the new `Mail` command with the conditional

```
if($object->takealook_FILE !='' && filesize($object->takealook_FILE) < 2024128) {
  $m->attach($object->takealook_FILE);
            }
```

Or should I put the code in the Mailable in `App\Mail\TaskDeliverResults.php` file? How?

Thank you.